# Change image link in excerpt to point to post

Tags: images, media, excerpt

By default, images included in an article link to the full-size-image url.

Having such an image in an excerpt shown on the start-page, because the more-tag was added after the image (which is intended), the image-thumbnail still links to the image URL.

**Which action has to be taken to make it link to the article?**
While keeping it pointing to the image url in the specific article-pages? (For my Fancybox)

Clarification: I don't mean Post-Thumbnails, just Images in the articles as shown in the specific article-page.

Comment: It might be helpful to paste the snippet of code you're currently using to display those posts on your start-page.

Comment: I am using the default Theme, Twenty Twelve.

The images are uploaded and included in the article by the builtin media-manager.

The excerpts are generated by adding the more-tag in the article.

Comment: So the images need to point to the image URL on the single posts page but to the article on the index page?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Images are embedded in post content as pretty much straight HTML.

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.10/wp_release/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/boat.jpg">
  <img src="http://192.168.1.10/wp_release/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/boat.jpg?w=300" alt="" title="boat" class="size-medium wp-image-544" height="198" width="300">
</a>
```

There is no easy way to alter that. You *can* alter it, but it means `regex`ing the post body content or using an html parser like [`Simple HTML DOM Parser`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/) (Not an endorsement, just an example).

The `regex` way would look something like this:

```
function replace_image_link_cb_101524($match) {
  global $post;
  if (!empty($match[2])) {
    $match[0] = preg_replace('|'.$match[1].'|',get_permalink($post),$match[0],1);
  }
  return $match[0];
}

function replace_image_link_101524($content) {
  if (is_archive()) {
    $pattern = '|<a.*?href="(.*)".*>?(<img.*?/?>)(?:</a>)?|';
    $content = preg_replace_callback($pattern,'replace_image_link_cb_101524',$content);
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_image_link_');
```

That well could be buggy. `regex` on markup is tricky at best.